# Will GeoServer run over Tomcat 10.x?

Tags: java-8, geoserver, sles, tomcat10

We're attempting to migrate our web application from Java 8 to Java 11, and Tomcat 9 to Tomcat 10, however we found out that we need to refactor the code to change javax.* entries by jakarta.* entries. The question is, will the most recent version of GeoServer run in Tomcat 10?
Thanks.

We already tried deploying GeoServer 2.19.2 on Tomcat 10 but didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

GeoServer is not compatible with Tomcat 10.x, it's not compatible with JakartaEE.
Stay with Tomcat 9, which is using Java2EE instead.

Comment: This is a RoadMap issue for GeoServer planning (and funding). See https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Jakarta-EE for the amount of work required.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done, with some massaging.  The issue is JaveEE to JakartaEE migration.  You can use a migration tool (https://github.com/apache/tomcat-jakartaee-migration) on the Geoserver WAR file.  I've used it with versions 2.21.3 and 2.20.2 and deployed them to Tomcat 10.